# Django1.8 (Django Rest Framework3.3.1) and Postgresql 9.3 - Programming Error

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, postgresql-9.3, django-1.8

I've created views in my Postgres Database that have links in Django Rest Framework. 
[image]

I have about 20 views altogether. On 7 of them - I keep getting this programming error:

```
ProgrammingError at /api/reports/
column report.event_type_id_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "report"."id", "report"."ev...
```

All 7 have the same exact error message. All of the views are based off one table with all the same column names. The column referenced in the table is event_type_id. NOT event_type_id_id. So I'm not sure where it's getting that from. If it had the same error on all of them - it would make a little more sense  but it's only 7.

I'm not sure where to begin even correcting this issue because I can't pinpoint what the exact problem is. I'm assuming it's on the database side and how django expects to receive something from the database - but I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: 
Exception Location:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
                            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
    def executemany(self, sql, param_list):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            return self.cursor.executemany(sql, param_list)
```

Report Model Update:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    event_type_id = models.ForeignKey(EventTypeRef, default='01')
    event_at = models.DateTimeField("Event Time")
    xxxxxx_id = models.ForeignKey(xxxxxx)
    xxxx = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    xxxxx_info = models.CharField(db_column='xxxxxInfo', max_length=56, blank=True)
    xxxx_tag = models.ForeignKey(xxxxxxxx, blank=True, null=True)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.event_type_id

    class Meta:
        managed= False,
        db_table = u'report'
        verbose_name_plural = "XXXXX Reports"
```

Comment: Could you post the `Report` model, please?

Comment: Just added it. All of the views pretty much have this same format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Django [`ForeignKey` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> **Behind the scenes, Django appends `"_id"` to the field name to create
>   its database column name.** In the above example, the database table for
>   the Car model will have a `manufacturer_id` column. (You can change this
>   explicitly by specifying `db_column`) However, your code should never
>   have to deal with the database column name, unless you write custom
>   SQL. You’ll always deal with the field names of your model object.

So, you should rename `event_type_id` to `event_type`